# The smallest n such that n^n mod m = 0

Tags: python, algorithm, math, prime-factoring

You have a natural number m.

You need to write a function f(m) which finds the smallest positive number n such that n^n≡0 mod m.

In other words n^n is divisible by m.

For example:

```
f(13) = 13
f(420) = 210
f(666) = 222
f(1234567890) = 411522630
```

And this is my code for python.

```
import math

def f(m: int) -> int:
    t = math.isqrt(m) + 1
    primes = [1 for i in range(0, t)]

    maxCount = 0
    factors = []
    p = 2

    result = 1

    while p < t and p < m:
        if primes[p] == 1 and m % p == 0:
            for i in range(p + p, t):
                primes[i] = 0

            c = 0
            while m % p == 0:
                m = m // p
                c += 1
            if maxCount < c:
                maxCount = c
            result *= p
            factors.append(p)
        p += 1
    factors.append(p)
    if m > 1:
        result *= m
    if maxCount <= result:
        return result
    p1 = math.ceil(maxCount / result)
    for p in primes:
        if p >= p1:
            return result * p
    return result
```

The problem is, the result is usually gets bigger than it has to be.
If you have ever met this question before, please help me how can I solve this problem.

I have tried to find the mathematical methods, and this code is what I have reached so far.
I hope this code will get me the smallest result, but it gets bigger than I expected.

Comment: There's almost certainly a mathematical method, you can ask on [math.se].

Comment: A simpler, possibly less efficient, approach is to use modular arithmetic: a*b mod m = (a mod m)*(b mod m) mod m. So you can compute n^n mod m by repeated multiplying by n and taking the result modulo m, that way you avoid having to explicitly calculate n^n and also you don't need to consider prime factors. Since that's simple, maybe get that working first, then use that to test more complicated approaches.

Comment: Someone had a comment earlier hinting at the answer. Consider the unique prime-power factorization of m, m = pow(p1,e1)\*pow(p2, e2)\*...\*pow(pk,ek).  Now we know m\*\*m=0 mod m, so m is the upper bound. We also know the smallest possible candidate is p1\*p2\*...\*pk. Let E=max(e1,e2,...,ek). Now think about when (p1\*p2\*...\*pk) \*\* (p1\*p2\*...\*pk) = 0 mod m and how that relates to E.

Answer (score 5):

If m divides n<sup>n</sup>, Then all the prime factors of m must also be factors of n<sup>n</sup>.

Since exponentiation doesn't introduce any new prime factors, n itself must also have all the prime factors of m.

Let P be the product of the unique prime factors of m.  Since n needs all of these factors, it will be a multiple of P.

n = P will work, i.e. P<sup>P</sup> will be divisible by m, *unless* at least one of the prime factors of m has a power greater than P.

For example, if m = 3x2<sup>7</sup>, then P = 6, and 6<sup>6</sup> is not divisible by 3x2<sup>7</sup>, because it only has 2<sup>6</sup>.

However, if you just start with i=1 and just try each n = P*i in sequence, then you will never have to count very far before you find a multiple of m, because the powers of the prime factors in m are limited by the length of m.

Comment: No need to _try_ each `i` -- it'll be the roof of the largest power in `m` divided by `P`.

Comment: No, sometimes it's smaller, because `i` may share a factor with `P`, and that increases the power in the base.

Comment: That's what I think. And the only problem is, I cannot find the way to calc the minimum P.

Comment: Your code already finds all the prime factors

Answer (score -2):

To solve this problem, we will follow the given steps:

Start with n = 1.

Check if n ^n  mod m = 0.
If true, return n.

If false, increment n and repeat step 2.

Below is the Python code that implements the function:

```
def f(m):
    n = 1
    while True:
        if pow(n, n, m) == 0:
            return n
        n += 1

# Test the function with given examples
print(f(13))  # 13
print(f(420))  # 210
print(f(666))  # 222
print(f(1234567890))  # 411522630
```

This function uses the built-in pow function with three arguments: pow(a, b, m) computes
a^b mod m efficiently. This allows the program to compute large powers modulo m without having to compute the large power directly.

Note: For very large values of m, this algorithm might take a considerable amount of time because it checks each possible value of n iteratively.

Comment: This just brute-forces the answer, which why this be a good solution? =)

Comment: how long did it take to calculate the last line

Comment: This code will sure get the right result, but it will take long time.
And what I hope to get is an optimized - better performance code.